# Brushless 3-phase motor (BLDC) in generator mode dropping current

Tags: generator, brushless-dc-motor

I am making a winch that will spool out line under tension.  I've had success using an old brushed motor.  I short the windings, so that when I unspool the line, the motor provides braking torque and line tension.  The old motor is not powerful enough, so I upgraded to a stronger, brushless motor with 5000w power rating.

Here's the problem: as I unspool the line from this motor, it builds torque until it reaches a certain value (130lb in my case), and then the current and torque suddenly drop to zero and then build up again, then drop again.

The motor has 3 phases (which are shorted for the generator mode) and a 5-pin hall sensor connector (unused here).  Here's the exact motor: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Electric-bike-brushless-dc-hub-motor-5000w-for-electric-bicycle-5kw-ebike-hub-motor/32234157960.html

Why is it dropping the current in generator mode?  Do these motors have some kind of a built-in internal protection?  I thought that there was nothing inside but windings and magnets (and halls), as this one uses an external 100Amp controller.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
PS.  Does this 3-phase brushless generate AC or pulse DC?

Comment: I am not expert on motor control. But here are some basic questions that anyone might want answered, to help you. Are you using a commercial controller with the motor? Do you disconnect the controller when spooling out wire? Is the motor wired as a "Wye" or "delta" configuration. I am guessing "Wye." When you say you shorted the windings together for generator mode are the three windings also shorted to ground, or just to each other? Is there any load to ground on the generator at all?

Comment: When you take away the controller from a brushless DC motor, it is essentially a permanent magnet synchronous motor (AC). If you hook up the phases to different channels of an oscilloscope and spin the motor shaft somehow (maybe with a power drill or something) you will see a three phase voltage waveform. Might be sinusoidal or kind of trapezoidal. In generator mode, I believe you can achieve constant drag during spooling by putting resistors from each phase to ground. Because the sum of power delivered to all resistors is virtually constant under constant speed.

Comment: MKeith, thanks for the informative response. You indeed got me thinking.  The motor is likely a Wye, but I don't know for sure.  Yes, the controller is disconnected when I unspool line.  There are three wires from the phases and they are just shorted to each other.  The most glaring thing from your post is that I don't have a ground.  I don' have any ground wire and have no idea how I would introduce ground into the system here!

Comment: The reason I don't use resistors is because they would cut the current and cut the torque. The phase to phase resistance is 0.3 ohm.  If I add even another 0.3 ohm, it will cut the current and the turque in half.  Even if I get such resistors (I was gonna use heating elements), how would I connect them to "ground"?  The motor does not appear to have any...

Comment: Exactly how are you shorting the phases to each other? What diameter is the winch drum?

Comment: If no ground, then it must be delta configuration. This is NOT my area of expertise. Maybe wait for someone more knowledgeable to chime in. I was under the impression that most BLDC's have a ground connection. If it is delta, then the resistors should be connected in delta, too. Think about this: You are trying to deliver maximum power to the resistors. There is probably an optimal resistor value for doing that, and it is probably not "as close to zero as possible." The fact that the drag is not constant tells you something is off.

Comment: It is likely that there is some protection circuit inside the motor. I experimented with several smaller BLDC motors today connected as you described and they all generate current (and braking torque) proportional to speed up to 100A per phase, where I hit the limit of the power source.

Comment: The winch drum diameter is 21 inches, but the amount of rope on it is such that the diameter is about 17 inches.  The drag is constant if it's below a certain value.  If I take it higher (by speeding up the car that unspools the line) than 130lb of tension reading, the torque abruptly drops to zero and then builds up again almost immediately, then drops abruptly to zero again (as I continue to spool out the line fast).

Comment: Oleg, I wish I had your results! This is all I need from this motor - just working as a generator and generating steady torque and current up to about 80A (the motor is rated to handle up to 350A peak current and 80-100A continuous).

Comment: As far as the "optimal value of the resistors," do I approach it on a per-phase basis?  In other words, if my winching requires about 3kw of power, do I place a heating element of, say 1000w per phase, on each phase for a total of 3000w of load, or do I put 3000w of load on each phase separately (for a total of 9000w)?  Just in case, here's what the "concoction" looks like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ttp0LcDuJY

Comment: Yes, 1000 W per phase. But when calculating the electric power, use 1000 = V^2/R where V is the RMS voltage of the open-circuit back EMF for one phase and R is the resistive load for one phase. How fast is the car going or how fast do you want it to go? I am looking for the Linear speed of the line feeding out. Want to double check your mechanical power calculation.

Answer (score 2):

### The load angle

Your BLDC behaves like a synchronous machine, the only difference is that you give it block voltages instead of sinusoidal voltages as input. That means that the principles of the synchronous machine can be used on your machine.

The load angle is a measure (as the name says) of the loading of the machine. As you can see from the figure below it is the relative displacement of the rotor in regard to the field axis. 
[image: Load angle in relation to flux lines]

The second figure shows you how the torque(or power) of the machine depends on the load angle. You can see that there is a maximum at \$90^\circ\$. After this points the flux lines *tear apart*, and the torque reduces. That means if you pass this point your motor will loose torque and slow down.

[image: Torque dependence in regard to load angle]

The simplified equation describing this behavior is:
$$
T=\frac{3UE}{X_s\omega}\sin\delta
$$

For references and a short explanation look [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_motor#Steady_state_stability_limit).

EDIT: In regard to the comment

The synchronicity is irrelevant, that is true. The thing that is worth thinking about is the stability. Let's do a little calculation, the induced voltage is divided between the short circuit resistance and the reactance of the machine(we will neglect \$R_{SC}\$ as needed):

\begin{equation}
\underline{E}={{jX_s}\underline{I}+R_{SC}\underline{I}}\nonumber\\
E\angle\delta={{jX_s}I\angle\varphi+R_{SC}I\angle\varphi}\\
I\angle\varphi=\frac{E\angle\delta}{{jX_s}+R_{SC}}; R_{SC}<<X_s\\
I\angle\varphi=\frac{E\angle(\delta-90^\circ)}{{X_s}}\\
I\angle-\varphi=\frac{E\angle(\delta-90^\circ-2\varphi)}{{X_s}}
\end{equation}

Let's multiply by the current to get the losses (multiply by\$\underline{I}^*\$):
$$
IE\angle(\delta-\varphi)={{jX_s}I^2+R_{SC}I^2}
$$

The losses are the last term \$P_{loss}=R_{SC}I^2\$, we can equalize them with the real part of the rest of the equation:
$$
P_{loss}=\mathfrak{R}\{IE\angle(\delta-\varphi)-{jX_s}I^2\}\\
P_{loss}=\mathfrak{R}\{\frac{E\angle(\delta)E\angle(\delta-90^\circ-2\varphi)}{{X_s}}\}\\
P_{loss}=\frac{E^2\cos(2\delta-2\phi-90)}{{X_s}}
$$

These are the losses, not really comparable to the previos torque equation. Let's look what happens to the load angle in the meantime:
$$
1\angle\delta=\frac{{jX_s}I\angle\varphi+R_{SC}I\angle\varphi}{E}; R_{SC}<<X_s\\
1\angle\delta=\frac{{X_s}I\angle(\varphi+90)}{E}\\
\delta=\varphi+90
$$
For an ideal short, it will be unstable as you can see from the last equation. Put some resistors instead of a short, it should work better. Capacitors would help too, just calculate it first with the given equations. Watch out for three phases, this is the one phase calculation!

Comment: In synchronous machines, the rotation is in sync with the supplied AC.  But in a generator mode, there is no supplied AC, so I would think synchronicity becomes irrelevant.  Yes, the torque would vary FOR EACH COIL as presented in the figure above, but the motor has at least 6 coils, and that pulsating effect is not felt.  I am having more than just torque oscillation caused by passing magnets.  I am getting a compete drop in current for 1-2 seconds at a time.

Comment: @Greg Edited the question, added some calculations.

Comment: I don't really understand this. I mean, I haven't taken the trouble to try. But intuitively, it makes sense that capacitors could help. Because we do want the current to be out of phase with the back EMF in order to produce drag. As I said before, it is a power transfer problem. We want to maximize the transfer of power to some load. If the source impedance of the synchronous machine is reactive in generator mode, then a matching network could help.

Comment: @Kurtovic - how does your calculation explain why the same phenomenon does not happen with a brushed motor (see my latest comment at bottom of page)?  Also, what place and role do capacitors have in the system? Are they hooked up parallel to the braking resistors?

Comment: @Greg It depends a bit on the kind of brushed motor you had attached, do you know it was PM, series or parallel excited? They behave differently so the explanation varies. For the case of the caps, they compensate the inductivity of the motor, therefore you have no voltage drop, what gives you a higher current for the same rotation speed of the generator. For \$X_c=1/(\omega C)\$ and \$X_L=\omega L\$ full compensation is for the frequency of \$X_c=X_L\$ or \$\omega=\sqrt{1/(LC)}\$. \$\omega\$ is the electric frequency, it can be calculated as \$p\omega_{mech}=\omega\$ .....

Comment: @Greg where p is the number of pole pairs of the machine. It is hard to find the right value (as you don't know the rotation speed exactly). You can skip them and just add resistors, this will have a similar effect. The resistance will be dominant in comparison to the inductivity, so you will be ok. You could search for a 3ph heater(of a large enough rating), and connect it instead of shorting it. You must be careful as to not overheat the system!! Make an experiment, measure the voltage and the current going to the heater, find the rotation speed at which you get...

Comment: ...the rated power of the heater. If you measure phase to phase voltage you can calculate the power by doing: \$P=\sqrt{3}UI\$. This is an approximation, but it will fit you. Don't drive it faster than this, as not to kill the whole setup! I'm not sure 5kW it will be enough for your application though. (Idea, you can take 3 smaller heaters and connect them between the terminals, Delta will be good, as the declared output voltage is only 48V)

Comment: @Kurtovic: Regarding the brushed motor, it's a PM motor (electric scooter motor). I have used a resitor with the brushed motor using a 1500w space heater.  To not kill the torque, it ended up being 0.5ohm (so I cut the heating element into several parallel segments) and even then my torque went from 35kg' to 18kg' at the same rpms.

Comment: Okay. The brushed motor with PM excitement is a linear machine, that means while running as a generator you will simply stay on a linear current-rpm relationship until it dies. Another thing for the heating element for the BLDC, think about the voltage rating and how you can adapt a 110V(220V) heater for 48V (nominal). You will have less than 48V except if it spins near the nominal speed (just to remember). EMF is \$E=\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\$, as crude approximation. So it is dependent on the frequency.

Comment: @Kurtovic: As for the big motor, the max RPMs are about 450. It's rated for 900. It has 6 pole pairs. It never gets warm (instead it gives me the problem I'm solving here).  The resistors will reduce torque at given rpms and will make it necessary to drive faster to achieve the same torque.

Comment: The BL motor is also a PM motor, rated for 900rpm, 72V, 100A current, 350A peak current. But because it's BL, it's not linear or has some other quirks? I think we are close to something here...

Comment: I am treating the heater just as a powerful resistor (which it is). If it can handle 1500w at 120v, it is rated for 12.5A and has resistance of 9.6 ohm. I turned it into a 0.5ohm resistor of the same power by chopping it up and connecting the pieces in parallel.  I can take apart another one and make three 500w resistors of 1ohm.  Even if they burn out, it's not a problem now. My duty cycle is less than 1-2 minutes.  But I need to get the system up to 60kg of continuous torque.

Comment: Your motor is rated for 140Nm, but you could solve it mechanically, as torque actually is \$M=F\cdot d\$. Therefore you can take a very small diameter spindle and get a high braking force out of it. Think of it as a quasi-gearbox. Because of the smaller diameter you need more rotations to spool it, therefore the motor can spin faster what is beneficial for the EMF. But anyways take the heaters too, but watch the calculations (wye or delta connection, sqrt(3)).

Comment: Yeah, I've accounted for that. 140Nm is 140kgdm.  My radius is 15-20cm, so the torque is at least half of 140kg', i.e., 70kg'. I am trying to get 55kg'-60kg'.  I don't mind if it's even limited to that, as long as it STAYS CONTINUOUS, as with the brushed motor.  But it drops to zero as if the motor's magnets temporarily disappear.  If they cancel each other out when the fields get too strong, why doesn't the same thing happen on the brushed? - Hate being helpless :)

Comment: At the brushed motor, you only have torque building current. The BLDC motor has two components of current, one is torque building\$i_q\$, the other is either field strengthening or weakening\$i_d\$. If you are in generator mode without any control strategy, you are letting the currents form on their own. The problem with short circuits on your motor is that it could demagnetize the magnets. If you pass the coercitive field strength \$H_c\$, you demagnetize that part of the magnet(usually edges). Another thing to think about: optimal power transmission. Maximum power transmission happens when..

Comment: impedances match. Think about speakers (if you haven't had any contact with this). Because of this you should match the impedance of your load to your generator. So adding the resistances will be helpful. Have you tried the new configuration already??

Comment: @Kurtovic: "BLDC motor has to components of current" - never heard of this before; would be nice to find some reading on this...

Comment: Tried the new configuration today: 3 resistors of 0.5Ohm in delta config (wye would merely have double that, i.e., 1 Ohm in each phase).  Drove the car to 20mph. Current went up to 40A, torque went up to only 70 lb.  Not sure if I would have gotten the dreaded "drop" at higher speeds (over 20mph is impractical for my application anyway).  Thus: gonna cut the braking resistors' value in half, that should take me up to 140-150lb.  If the "drop" doesn't happen then within my range of speed, it'll be great.

Comment: The generated current was AC, unlike my brushed, so that must definitely be a factor in the difference in behavior (no drop for brushed vs drop for bldc).  Hence, another option will be to hook up the three phases of the bldc to a 3-phase diode 100A rectifier and then just use one resistor for load (instead of the currently used 3).  I've ordered a 3-phase rectifier from China, but they sent me a regular diode bridge. Now waiting for a replacement.

Comment: The rectifier is a possibility, but in your case it seems to be far more expensive than proper resistors. It is better to keep it as simple as possible for the given function. You can add resistors of the same value in parallel to create 0.25 instead of 0.5\$\mathrm{\Omega}\$. Regarding the current components, you can look up [vector control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_control_(motor)), or field oriented control.

Comment: I finally tested a different set of resistors. Three 0.25 Ohms in parallel per phase.  My ohm-meter is showing such resistance (0.25/3) as zero.  I couldn't measure the current or voltage because of this, but I got a steady torque of 120lb !  Still don't know all the theory, but somehow resisters prevent the current drops I was seeing before.  The drops happened at 130lb, so it remains to be seen if I can take this thing to torques above 130lb and still have steady torque without the sudden drops.

Comment: @Kurtovic: I am at a loss for a scientific explanation, but somehow 0.08 Ohm per phase made a difference?!  When shorted, the current would build put to the value that produced 130lb of torque and then would drop and start 1-sec cycles.  With 0.08 Ohm of resistance per phase, the current goes to the value producing 125lb of torque and stays there without dropping.  Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you're stalling (stopping) the rotor, there's a car pulling it...

However, remember the generated current generates its own field, opposing the PM field. At some point there will be (partial) field cancellation, and thus reduced voltage generation, reduced stall current, reduced torque, at a point where the field from one pole is falling off anyway and before the next pole fully engages. It's a little more complex than this, when a rotor pole is between two stator poles, the phase of the voltage it generates in each will be different. I don't have a good enough understanding to describe it in more detail.

So there will be a point between poles at which the motor "lets go", before the field increases again at the next pole.

With suitable resistances instead of a short you will be able to pull it round by hand and feel the cogging as each pole engages.

I think that imposes an upper limit on the braking you can achieve from the motor : to get more, you need a bigger motor, or a smaller diameter winch drum, or gearing.

EDIT : given the information that the pulsation is at 1-2second intervals, it's clearly not the poles cogging.

I suspect the start/stop motion may be from the cable acting as a spring, storing energy while the motor brakes efficiently, but it's not clear why the brushed DC motor acted differently, sorry.

Comment: The "certain point between poles" corresponds to "the middle of a pole" for another phase. There is no point that a BLDC cannot develop torque, just points of reduced torque due to cogging

Comment: @JonRB - Not exactly - you are correct about the exact midpoint between poles, but that's not where the torque troughs occur.

Comment: They do actually.If you look at the line-line backEMF of a BLDC machine, especially "rectified" in relation to absolute rotor position, there are troughs that correspond to the points of commutation as a rotor pole crosses between two teeth. This however does not result in a point of zero torque otherwise you would have breakout issues and specific starting & parking requirements when dealing with BLDC machine. These troughs are compounded by motor-drives as they commutate the stator current & produce higher torque ripple. Thus the statement that the "motor "lets go" isn't correct

Comment: I can pull it by hand even when it's shorted.  It creates steady torque when I spin in by hand slowly.  When I spin it with a car much faster than by hand, the torque starts to "pulsate" (abruptly drops and gradually rises) in 1-2 second intervals (much slower than the phase rotation speed).

Comment: Just a quick comment. If you imagine a BLDC with three phase sinusoidal back emf being used as a generator, the total instantaneous voltage output is actually constant at constant speed. For a trapezoidal back emf, I guess this is not true, or doesn't have to be true, but is still an approximation of the truth. Anyway, constant voltage + resistive load implies smooth torque characteristic. So a PMSM used as a generator would have drag but zero torque ripple with a resistive load. The trapezoidal EMF might give rise to some torque ripple, but not create detents.

Answer (score 0):

In short your generation capability is a lot higher than your load.

You are essentially "plugging" the machine, shorting the 3phases together.

The backEMF constant is proportional to speed. As the rotor starts to turn, voltage is induced. Since the phases are shorted a current will flow which in turn generates a torque, a torque that will try to oppose your load.

The faster the rotor goes, the more torque is generated ...

Depending on specifics of the electrical machine, you could be experiencing field weakening as an increase in speed will result in increase in current which will shift the stator flux vector with respect to the rotor flux vector, which results in a drop in developed torque -> current.

Solutions? Some series resistance would limit the current and thus the torque but that is a waste.  Some gearing would help. Smaller cog on the load, larger on the rotor.  Some frictional component equally would help but again that's loss

Also a BLDC machine will generate an AC backEMF, it will not be a pure sine wave (unless the emag designer was ... Quick). It will have a slightly flatter top

Comment: "In short your generation capability is a lot higher than your load." So you are saying that the shorted wires are not strong enough load to absorb the generated current?  If I add resistors across the windings, they will limit the current and will dissipate the generated energy as heat.  Even though it is a waste of sorts, I'd be fine with it.  In frichtion-based systems, such dissipation is not channeled anywhere specific and results in brakes overheating, etc.

Comment: "You are essentially "plugging" the machine, shorting the 3phases together."  I thought this would only be applicable if the motor was running "direct", connected to a power source.  I am running it in "reverse", by spinning it mechnically and generating current.

Comment: "shorted wires not strong enough"  -  thats dependent on what you pick but that wasn't what I was alluding to. Thinking a bit more about your situation, without knowing specifics of the machine (especially terminal inductance) you are quite likely experiencing field weakening at the top speed where the stator inductance is shifting the current w.r.t. backEMF and thus are no longer in phase. If this carries on then the zero torque point will be reached and current will drop off

Comment: yeah, it looks like either field weakening or resistance growing/current weakening. This doesn't happen with a similarly designed brushed motor (http://www.ebay.com/itm/48-Volt-1000-Watt-Drive-Motor-Scooter-Bike-48V-1000W-MY1020-M-ST12-US-Stock-TU-/381133396486?pt=Motorcycles_Parts_Accessories&hash=item58bd521a06&vxp=mtr) as opposed to this brushless (http://www.ebay.com/itm/POWER-48V-1500W-Electric-Scooter-Brushless-Motor-For-E-Scooter-5600-RPM-FAST-/171475135134?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27ecb6ea9e)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am supposed to post as a separate answer to my own question or just use comments.  I've done a bunch of comments (see above), but this one was too long.

"What is occurring here is the generated torque is higher that your load so the rotor stalls."  Interesting... The motor is not driving anything.  It is disconnected from any power supply.  The "generated torque is higher" than what load? - There's no load, the motor is not driving anything, it's disconnected from power.  The torque only opposes the mechanical rotation. The mechanical rotation never stops, as the car unspooling the line is way stronger that this motor.  What stops is the torque, at which point the rotation accelerates suddenly (b/c there's no opposing torque at that moment), and then slows down again when the torque is back.  It didn't happen on a burshed motor that I used to try this first.  Maybe the current gets so high that it messes up the next phase's magnetic field... - Your second explanation seems to make a lot more sense.  I had no idea the flux direction changed at higher current.  Again, didn't happen with the brushed motor - that sucker produced torque even as it would start smoking at high current (35A while rated at 25A).

I'll try the limiting resistors, but I have now had two BLDC motors that don't produce consistent torque as generators (I just tried another BLDC that I have).  Interesting phenomenon.  The torque builds up  and is continuous to certain RPMs of external mechanical rotation, and then starts to disappear for 1-2 seconds and only comes back in short spurts after that.  The manufacturer just told me the motor has no internal over-current protection.  I can't think of any theoretical reason why BLDCs would behave this way.  Since they produce AC, I'll try a 3-phase diode rectifier and a low-resistance heating element as a load.

Comment: You can edit your own question to add the new information and clarifications, rather than long comments or an "answer"

Comment: Permanent magnet motors and generators are very efficient. Here is what I propose. Power = force * speed. You know what force you want. You know what speed you want it to happen at. Calculate that power in Watts. Call it P. Spin up the motor to the target speed with no electric load on the phases. Measure or estimate the RMS voltage from any one wire to any other. Call that V. The resistor (or heater element) you need can be calculated using P/3 = V^2/R. Now, when you load the generator, the voltage will sag, but hopefully not enough to throw off the calculation.

Comment: Don't rectify an AC signal just to attach a resistive load. Just apply the resistive load directly. Actually three resistive loads. Conceptually, arrange the resistors in a delta configuration (triangle) and connect one wire to each corner.

Comment: I think you are overheating the core. When you do, flux density crashes, reducing torque. Then it cools and comes back up. Short-circuiting the coils is not going to produce the maximum torque, nor maximum total heat, but it will produce the maximum current and heat in the windings. So far you have been assuming that current in the windings is good because it creates torque, and that is why you are hesitant to add any resistance. I am looking at it from conservation of energy. For a motor at a given speed, maximum drag will occur when load is optimized for maximum total heating.

Comment: Productive discussion:) Yes, P=F*v. F=130lbf=60kgf=600N (g=9.8 ~10). v=10mph=4.5m/s. P=600*4.5=2700 Watts.  The motor is rated for 5000w, and I am trying to get it to pull at 150lbf by speeding the car (and thus linear line speed) past 10mph.  When I do that, the torque simply drops to zero and then re-builds back to about 60lb and then drops again, such cycles being 1-2 sec.  The car never exceeds 12-15mph.  So even at max, P=700N*5.5m/s=3850w ~4000w.

Comment: P/3 ~1350w. RPM at 15mph linear speed is about 250.  V (based on motor's constant) at 250rpm will be 25 Volts. Current I without any resistors is limited by R of phase windings and is V/R=25/0.3=83.3A.

Comment: Perhaps I am exceeding the motor's capability when I get to over 150lb of torque, over 250RPM and over 12-15mph linear speed.  Let's say I get the current up to 200-300A.  My brushed motor heats up like crazy but still produces constant torque (max it capable of). But this brushless sucker drops the torque to zero!  And it is not even warm!  So maybe some windings are already very hot inside and it's not yet felt on the outside of the motor. So the hot windings do something to drop the current severely.

Comment: I am "overheating the core." Let's explore this. Does the windings' resistance get much higher (like with a lamp) when they get hot and so the current drops?  Are the magnets of the rotor getting their field nullified b/c of some heat?  Why doesn't this happen with a similar brushed motor, only with the two brushless ones?

Comment: @mkeith: why do you advise not to rectify the generated current but to apply resistive load directly? (Both options are available to me.)

Comment: Don't rectify only because it is not needed for a resistive load. It will get just as hot without rectification.

Comment: Over-heating is just a theory. Keeping in mind that I do not know a lot about motors. What I was thinking is that when the core material gets hot enough (Curie point), it would lose its magnetic permeability. This would cause the motor to essentially stop being a motor. So the torque is suddenly greatly reduced. Since it is still spinning, it cools down. Then the torque goes back up and the cycle repeats. The heat must be going somewhere, right? I believe that if your magnets overheat, the motor will be permanently ruined, so I don't suspect that.

Comment: I have no theory about why the same phenomenon does not apply to brushed motor.

Comment: One more point. If the motor is rated for 5kw of input power, remember that most of that power is not dissipated inside the motor. Most of it is converted to mechanical work and if it is dissipated as friction, the friction is outside the motor. But as a short-circuited generator, pretty much 100% of the mechanical power must be dissipated inside the motor.

Comment: Yeah.  I just tested it again, and same result - first provides constant torque and then starts cutting in and out at 130lb of tension. It doesn't get hot at all.  Then I switched back to the brushed one: 60 lb of torque max, but it continues at that same value even as I continue to increase the applied mechanical RPMs. It gets quite warm, yet doesn't drop the torque...  Both motors dissipate all the braking energy in their windings inside (which is fine cos my duty cycle is only a few minutes).

Comment: That's actually 80lb (not 60) continuous tension for the 1000w brushed.  I need 150lb continous tension.  5000w brushless should be enough except for my unexpected cut-off at 130lb in continuous torque, apparently due to its brushless nature.